Does FireDAC support SQLite extensions?
I'm trying to load the mathematical statistics module stats from the sqlean-win-x86.zip archive (32-bit version) for SQLite database using FireDAC Connection Editor (SQL Script tab):
SELECT load_extension('C:\Test\stats');

But I always get the following error:

The specified module could not be found

When I use stats from sqlean-win-x64.zip (64-bit version), I'm getting another error:

%1 is not a valid Win32 application

This means that FireDAC was able to find the specified module.
The Extensions parameter in the Definition tab is set to True and the connection to a database is successful.
What am I doing wrong? Does FireDAC support SQLite extensions?
I'm using RAD Studio 11.2 and its FireDAC 28.0.0.
SQLite Studio loads the same extension from the same folder without any problem.

To use FireDAC SQLite driver extensions you should enable them by adding "Extensions=True" to your connection parameters. I think, you did this. Then running a simple test application with sqlean-win-x86.zip, I am getting Windows system error (translated): "Cannot run program, because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is not found on this computer".

@da-soft Yes, I did.  So you mean the problem is actually with the missing dependencies? Looks similar to this problem: https://forum.qt.io/topic/100380/where-does-the-qt-sqlite-plugin-look-for-extension-libraries/9

@Bruce the problem with a "module could not be found" error is that it doesn't tell you which module is missing. Yes, it could be a dependent module rather than the main module. Use a tool like Dependency Walker or Process Monitor to see which module is not loading correctly.

@RemyLebeau The Dependency Walker shows that the module libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll could not be found. I tried different versions of it, but I never get the "right" one, as I always get the error: "The specified procedure could not be found". This is a common problem with GCC/MinGW, so I asked the extension developer for help. Interesting fact: SQLite Studio doesn't have this module either, but loads the extension without a problem. Magic!

@RemyLebeau other extensions from the sqlean-win-x86.zip archive that do not have missing modules will also not work in FireDAC: "The specified procedure could not be found". However, SQLite Studio and DB Browser for SQLite work fine.
